# regex in a for loop

Tags: php, expression

I have a string like this:

```
1. Zentrallager # TF Schrankwandp (u) -EG- 2. ASH 25 # TF silentglider (u) WS 3. Gutinedu # TF ottomatic 4. Deep Space Three # TF Kleissi1978 F & P 5. crafted by trapper12 # TF trapper12 VR 6. -8- # TF Mrs-Shooter (u) -=SC=- 7. 8. Standard Libelle # TF silentglider (u) WS 9. crafted by phiLLLdd # TF phiLLLdd -=SC=- 10. V8 Vote111 (u) 3R 11. Nimbus # TF silentglider (u) WS 12. Speed Astir # TF silentglider (u) WS 13. I Want My Tears Back # TF KlappstuhI (u) ReX 14. RK-Weporinag # TF ImperatorMar (gu) -=SC=- 15. RK-Hohoieugo # TF -sledge- (gu) > TdE < 16. Oununu # TF Xantros
```

and I need the values between the "1." and "2." and "2." and "3." .......

My try looks like this:

```
for($i=1;$i<16;$i++){ // I know there are ever 16 counts
     $j = $i+1;
     $regex = "/$i\. (.*) $j\./";
     preg_match_all($regex, strval($string),$matches);}
```

My result is empty every time. Matches count is 0. Why?

The variable is definitely a string and the regular expression is functional in some online testers but not in my script.

Comment: Check the regex first. I guess it's not correct. Try various combination on [gskinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Comment: Are there line breaks between those items? If so, you should use the special characters `^` and `$` to mark the start and end of the line respectively. It'll make it a lot easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$arr=preg_split ("/[\d|\d\d]\./", $yourstring)
```

Now $arr[n] will contain part n+1 of the string

Comment: Love this solution. $arr[n] will actually contain part $n though, not $n+1 (since $arr[0] will be a blank string)